# iphone 4 verizon cdma unlocked in india and uprgaded to newer version cydia not installed

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, upgrade, unlock

I have an iPhone 4 (CDMA), bought it to India and unlocked unofficially by jailbreaking.

Recently I upgraded to iOS 6.1.2, and now Cydia is missing. Everything else is working fine; I can make calls, use internet and Wi-Fi, however is gone from my phone.

How can I install Cydia again? I am afraid of Jailbreaking my iPhone again in case it will lock the phone again. Is there a method of installing Cydia back without reverting the unlock?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. To avoid getting answers that don't really solve your problem, the question will be closed FOR NOW until it can be improved. Please edit your question to make it clearer so we can reopen it. Read [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more ideas to improve the question. Confusing questions are closed so they don't attract a scattering of answers before they're in a form that is likely to get a clear answer; your question can be reopened at any time if you or someone on your behalf suitably amends it.

Comment: Sandeep, what version of iOS were you running before you upgraded? How did you upgrade? Through iTunes, or Over The Air (iPhone Settings > General > Software Update)?